# sharing same variables which is call frequently from ajax

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I am creating an web application in asp.net which have a batch process (takes about 2hrs to execute in background). I have created a static class which have some static variable to update the progress of the batch process. From web browser these variables are accessed through ajax to show the progress.

Now the problem is when ajax is called to accessed these static variable, browser is not responding until it gets response from the server. I think this is happening due to accessing same static variables from both ajax and background batch process at the same time. But when background batch process is not running, everything is fine.

Please help me to solve this or let me know the better way to do this.

bit of shared section

```
public static class ExecutionStatusLog
{
  public static string RunID;
  public static string ExecutionStatus;
  public static int RunningFlag = 0;        
  public static DateTime StartTime;
  public static DateTime EndTime;
  public static int count;
}
```

Comment: Show your code? Are you using locks to serialize access? Your batch process could acquire a lock on these shared variables and block everyone else.

Comment: no I am not using locks.I am adding bit of codes that is accessing by both ajax and batch process.

Comment: "browser is not responding until it gets response" - are you using synchronous ajax calls?

Comment: asynchronous ajax call is used.

Comment: What does "browser is not responding until it gets response from the server" mean?  The browser process goes unresponsive?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lock structure` in order to block access for two threads in same time

```
mutual exclusion problem
```

link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/c5kehkcz(v=vs.80).aspx

Note : You can also use Monitor, Mutex or Semaphore ...